# System.AddIn AddInView assembly strong name issue

Tags: appdomain, strongname, maf, system.addin

I've built up an application that works using the System.AddIn APIs.  Add-ins are currently activated in an external AppDomain with Internet trust.

In order to improve performance I've added strong names to all my pipeline components.  However as soon as I did this I get the following exception when trying to activate my add-in:

System.Security.SecurityException: That assembly does not allow partially trusted callers.

Looking at the fusion logs the error messages indicate this is due to the AddInView assembly not allowing partially trusted callers.  However, I've added the [assembly: AllowPartiallyTrustedCallers] attribute to the assembly.  The only assemblies AddInView references are:

1. System.
2. System.AddIn
3. System.AddIn.Contract

Any ideas how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add the

`[assembly:AllowPartiallyTrustedCallers]`

attribute to the AddInView and the AddInViewAdapters assemblies.